# Slick slider loads last anchor href regarding which slide is active

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, slick.js

Can someone help me with slick slider "bug". So, I am working on the Laravel project and I have one image plus some information and CTA button/anchor.

All of the information are loading properly except the href attribute at the anchor element.

Currently, it goes like this:

**FIRST SLIDE:** it will load information of the first slide but href from the **FOURTH**

**SECOND SLIDE:** it will load information of the first slide but href from the **FOURTH**

**THIRD SLIDE:** it will load information of the first slide but href from the **FOURTH**

**FOURTH SLIDE:** it will load information of the first slide but href from the ***THIRD***

Here is the HTML:

```html
                   <div class="col-lg-6 left_column">
                        <h3>Informations</h3>
                        <div class="slick_slider">
                            @if (count($infos) > 0)
                                @foreach ($infos as $info)
                                    <div>
                                        <h2>{{ $info->title}}</h2>                                       
                                        <a href="{{ route('service.show', 'slug' => $info->slug) }}">{{ $info->slug }}</a>
                                    </div>
                                @endforeach
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Here is some HTML part for the image with id `.slick_slider_nav`

Here is the JS part:

```js
    // Services slider

    $(".services_slider").slick({
        // infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: true,
        fade: true,
        cssEase: "linear",
        asNavFor: ".slick_slider_nav",
        prevArrow: "<img class='info_slick_arrow_left slick-prev' src='/images/arrow-left.svg'>",
        nextArrow: "<img class='info_slick_arrow_right slick-next' src='/images/arrow-right.svg'>",
        dots: false,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 5000,
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 991,
            settings: {
                arrows: false,
            },
        }, ],
    });
```

Comment: Where is your `usluga`? I don't see it in your code snippet

Comment: @NickVu $usluga is $service and it is pulled from the database. All of the information is pulled correctly just the script messes it around. When I remove the script initialization everything is fine. All buttons on their places as well as the related text.

Comment: `$info` is for slide info but your href gets from `$usluga` which is a difference source. How did you connect `$usluga` with `$info`?

Comment: @NickVu it was error due editing of the code. Now it is fine :)

Comment: the problem is still happening after your change?

Comment: Yes, this is the initial setup of how it is now with the issue. I just forgot to change that $usluga with $info :)

Comment: When you say _"it will load information of the first slide but href from the FOURTH"_, what do you actually mean by that? Are the slides _showing_ the wrong links (i.e., link _text_ of `$info->slug` is not what you are expecting), or are those links taken you to the wrong destination, when you click on them? What does the actual, _rendered_ HTML that your template produces look like?

Comment: @CBroe hi there. Yes, $info->slug is like "cached" (but it is not cached I cleared it in all ways haha). So at the first slide everything is from the $info with the id 1 and only the link is from the $info with id 4. So I have 4 iterations and first 3 will have link from the fourth iteration (last one) and when I go to the last iteration it has the link from the third.

Comment: Have you verified that the HTML source code generated by your template has everything in the right places? (And I mean the source code, not the DOM view.)

Comment: @CBroe yes. Everything was just fine. All the iterations and its information. Only the link was off.

Comment: _"Only the link was off."_ - just to be clear; only in the visual representation, not in the HTML? Then perhaps some CSS is interfering somehow.

Comment: only the links href was off * :D

Answer (score 0):

For this type of issue debugging is always the way to go to solve the issue quickly. It's unlikely the issue is related to Slick slider and more likely that it is either a database or a route issue. If you can show the method beneath `service.show` the community can also get a better picture of how the parameter is being utilised when you use the `route` helper.

Furthermore, if `$infos` is an *Eloquent* result / collection, you can utilise Laravel's helpers instead of count - eg: `!$infos->isEmpty()`

If this is a full URL you could just echo it without the route helper interpreting it (direct echo). If it's relative you need to include TRUE as the third parameter as per [the help docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-route).

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 left_column">
    <h3>Informations</h3>
    <div class="slick_slider">
        @if (!$infos->isEmpty())
            @foreach ($infos as $info)
                @php
                    // Check slug's data
                    dump($info->slug);
                    // or just dump the whole object
                    dump($info);
                @endphp
                <div>
                    <h2>{{ $info->title}}</h2>                                       
                    <a href="{{ route('service.show', 'slug' => $info->slug) }}">{{ $info->slug }}</a>
                    <br />- OR -<br />
                    <a href="{{ route('service.show', 'slug' => $info->slug, true) }}">{{ $info->slug }}</a>
                    <br />- OR -<br />
                    <a href="{{ $info->slug }}">{{ $info->slug }}</a>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

Finally, I would suggest you turn Slick slider off until you get the links correct, then turn Slick slider back on.

Comment: I already tried that and didn't work :( There was the same issue. I have recreated it with bootstrap carousel and redesigned it :) Thanks for the help guys